# WPF UI freezing when loading data into DatagGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, wpfdatagrid

Asynchronous data loading and throughout the process UI is responsive. But when this line `InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = results;` executes the UI freezes for a sec or more depending on the size of data. Is there a way to get rid of this UI freeze ?

```
private async void FetchInvoicesDataFunc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs  e)

 {
   List<Invoice> results = new List<Invoice>();
   ProgressBtn.Content = "Loading Data ...";
   await Task.Run(async() => results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(0, 500));  
   ProgressBtn.Content = "25% done...";
   await Task.Run(async() => results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(501, 1000)); 
   ProgressBtn.Content = "50% done...";
   await Task.Run(async() => results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(1001, 1500)); 
   ProgressBtn.Content = "75% done...";
   await Task.Run(async() => results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(1501, 2000));        
   InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = results;
   ProgressBtn.Content = "Loaded !";    
 }

 private async Task<List<Invoice>> FetchInvoiceDataAsync(int start, int end)
 {
   List<Invoice> result;
   using(var context = new Intelliventory_DBEntities() )
   {  
     result  = await context.Invoices.Where(b => b.InvoiceID >= start && b.InvoiceID <= end).Include(x => x.Customer).ToListAsync();      
   }

   return  result;
 }
```

Comment: Yes. Load less data. If it freezes then it is probably because you are trying to display too much data. Use pagination or some kind of dynamic loading. Nobody needs to see tens of thousands of records at the same time. Also, never write `await Task.Run(async () => ...)`. Just write `await results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(1501, 2000);`

Comment: i know i am using pagination but at least 100 rows should be shown and it still freezes for a lil and i think that's bad !

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in option for dynamic loading for wpf's DataGrid. You might want to look for some other control that supports dynamic loading. Perhaps write a custom one.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion sir ! even above code is hard for me to understand !

Comment: @FCin writing `await results.AddRange(await FetchInvoiceDataAsync(1501, 2000);` won't work as `AddRange` doesn't return a `Task`.
If he wants to add his results to the list outside of the GUI thread the solution is just fine.

Comment: @Dominik Yea, sorry, obviously it should be `results.AddRange(await ...)`; I miscopied the code.

Comment: @FCin and there is still no reason why he should't be doing what he does right now. Whats the problem of calling `AddRange` within a `Task`? I mean it won't have much of a benefit at 500 entries but it's still a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Could you post the XAML or component initialization for your DataGrid? Is Virtualization turned on and if so, what mode is set to? Scrollviewer mode as well

Comment: @Dominik This task is useless. It doesn't add any benefit and doesn't do anything. It just clutters the code.

Comment: @FCin simply wrong. Try it with some small test app and add 5000000 entries to a list within a button click event or something. When wrapping it into a task as he does he UI doesnt freeze. When not wrapping it the UI will freeze.

Comment: @Dominik The only reason why it would freeze is because it takes a lot of time for `AddRange` to add all elements. Here you can see he's adding 2000 elements. You are testing something removed from reality. Nobody adds 5 million items to list.

Comment: @FCin Exactly, it freezes cause it would take a lot of time. I just don't get the point of telling him to "never do" something for no reason at all. If he wants to add the elements in a task there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Dominik He creates additional useless tasks. These tasks are not needed here. They decrease readability and gain nothing.

Comment: @LadderLogic virtualization is enabled and mode is "Recycling". and data grid is not inside any stack-panel or non virtualizating element !

Comment: adding 100 rows and still it takes time to load and Ui hangs for a while now ui stays kinda unresponsive idk why !

Answer (score 0):

It freezes because you are trying to update ProgressBtn, which is an UI control from your async method. Not sure if you are calling this method from a background thread. If I were to do this, I would introduce a callback in the FetchInvoiceDataAsync() method to update the ProgressBtn control. In that callback method, I would call the dispatcher to update the UI. This should address all freezing issues.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
 {
      // Set property or change UI compomponents.              
 });
```

Apart from this, I would also recommend using a ListCollectionView instead of an observable collection. This will ensure that you can update the UI by calling refresh each time you have a new addition/s to the list.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Anyone who down voted, would be interesting to know why. Gives me an opportunity to improve at least

Comment: Because your statements are wrong. If he would change the UI-Element from a callback thread he would've gotten an exception. When he successfully updates his UI the call to change the UI-Element is already invoked by the correct dispatcher.

Also the statement "It freezes because you update the button... from your async method" is not right. A method that has been marked with the async method executes non-awaited calls just like a non-async method would do. The only difference between an async and a non-async-method are that you can await other async method-calls in an async-method

Comment: @Dominik All I wanted to say is he should have call one long processing method and passed a UI callback method which should have been called every time he hit a certain range to update the progress bar. 
Apart from that using a ListCollectionView always helps when you have to update UI frequently while the contents are being fetched in batches.
Regarding the async method it was not clear that's being invoked from UI thread or some background thread.